# plotGseaTable plotting multiple times on one pdf page instead of creating mutliple pages

Tags: r, plot

I am using the `fgsea` library to analyse some data for my lab, and right now I'm using the `plotGseaTable` function to, well, plot gsea tables. The basic function works fine:

```
library(fgsea)

data(examplePathways)
data(exampleRanks)

fgseaRes <- fgsea(examplePathways, exampleRanks, nperm=1000, minSize=15, maxSize=100)
topPathways <- fgseaRes[head(order(pval), n=15)][order(NES), pathway]

pdf(paste0(outdir, "testgseatable.pdf"))

plotGseaTable(examplePathways[topPathways], exampleRanks, fgseaRes, gseaParam=0.5)

dev.off()
```

[image: basic plotGseaTable plot]

However, once I try and look at multiple rankings and plot those, it prints all of the diagrams on a single page:

```
myranks_1 = rnorm(length(exampleRanks), 50, 7)
names(myranks_1) = names(exampleRanks)
myres_1 = fgsea(examplePathways, myranks_1, nperm=1000, minSize=15, maxSize=100)
mytop_1 = myres_1[head(order(pval), n=15)][order(NES), pathway]

myranks_2 = rnorm(length(exampleRanks), 50, 7)
names(myranks_2) = names(exampleRanks)
myres_2 = fgsea(examplePathways, myranks_2, nperm=1000, minSize=15, maxSize=100)
mytop_2 = myres_2[head(order(pval), n=15)][order(NES), pathway]
myranks_3 = rnorm(length(exampleRanks), 50, 7)
names(myranks_3) = names(exampleRanks)
myres_3 = fgsea(examplePathways, myranks_3, nperm=1000, minSize=15, maxSize=100)
mytop_3 = myres_3[head(order(pval), n=15)][order(NES), pathway]
myranks_4 = rnorm(length(exampleRanks), 50, 7)
names(myranks_4) = names(exampleRanks)
myres_4 = fgsea(examplePathways, myranks_4, nperm=1000, minSize=15, maxSize=100)
mytop_4 = myres_4[head(order(pval), n=15)][order(NES), pathway]
myranks_5 = rnorm(length(exampleRanks), 50, 7)
names(myranks_5) = names(exampleRanks)
myres_5 = fgsea(examplePathways, myranks_5, nperm=1000, minSize=15, maxSize=100)
mytop_5 = myres_5[head(order(pval), n=15)][order(NES), pathway]


pdf(paste0(outdir, "testgseatable_multiple.pdf"))

plotGseaTable(examplePathways[mytop_1], myranks_1, myres_1, gseaParam=0.5)
plotGseaTable(examplePathways[mytop_2], myranks_2, myres_2, gseaParam=0.5)
plotGseaTable(examplePathways[mytop_3], myranks_3, myres_3, gseaParam=0.5)
plotGseaTable(examplePathways[mytop_4], myranks_4, myres_4, gseaParam=0.5)
plotGseaTable(examplePathways[mytop_5], myranks_5, myres_5, gseaParam=0.5)

dev.off()
```

[image: unholy child of nightmares, multiple text plots on a single page, characters overlapping]

Is this a problem with the function? Is there some way to tell the `pdf()` function to start a new page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `plot.new()` command to force a page break in the pdf.

e.g

```
path <- "~/Desktop/tests/"
pdf(file = paste0(path, "myplot.pdf"))
par(mfrow = c(1,2))

plot(rnorm(10), main = 1)

plot.new()

plot(rnorm(10), main = 2)
plot(rnorm(10), main = 3)

dev.off()
```

[image: AA]

Comment: Doesn't change anything on my side. If you use plot as you did without the `par()` between each line, it will still create multiple pages.

Comment: @Whitehot True, but setting the `mfrow` should introduce page breaks (cf [this list](https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/can-the-pdf-output-page-break-be-controlled-manually-td877751.html)). Maybe add a `plot.new()` command after the `par()` call ?

Comment: `plot.new()` works, with or without `par(...)`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround using ggplot

I just added

> ggplot() + theme_void()

before running

> plotGseaTable()